# Wrong time display in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

Hello I have a problem with displaying data into lightning:inputfield

Here is my code of setting date to the field:

```
            if ((sourceValue == 'Yes') || (sourceValue == 'Ano') ) {
            console.log('Source value ' + sourceValue);
            var today = new Date();
            console.log('datum ' + today);
            var allCells = cmp.find("table-cell");
            if (allCells != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
                    var cell = allCells[i];
                    if (cell.get("v.id") == event.getSource().get("v.id") && cell.get("v.fieldName") == 'Date_of_PU__c')  {

                            allCells[i].set("v.value", today);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

problem is, when i console log "today", it will show me in browser correct date

[image]

and time but when i set it into the field, its wrong. Its exactly +2 hours.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was just that while displaying the information in the UI, Salesforce converts the date value to the timezone in which the user profile is configured.

So if the user profile is set to some GMT value, Salesforce automatically adjusts the time that is displayed in the datetime field for that particular timezone.

As I can see, You time Zone is set to **GMT+0200**. Hence you are seeing the 2 hours difference.

> So, In the console, you are getting the GMT value of time and on UI
>   you are getting the GMT+02:00 value of time.

The same difference you will get while querying from the backend and matching the UI value with it.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: and can I set it without any GMT+ and leave it simple UTC? I cant use toUTCString because i need to keep it in date format, I cant use String format.

Comment: You can change your time zone to GMT+00:00. GMT and UTC do not have any difference.

Comment: You can change your time zone by going in the personal setting. Click on your name in the right top of the page then select my setting and then personal and then language and time zone and select your desired time zone. Save it.